# Thymeleaf Reset counter in nested foreach

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

Is there anyway to reset counter in the nested foreach?

Please see my code below.

```
<div th:each="role, iter : ${roles}">
    <div th:text="role.Name">
        <div th:each="authority, iterAuth : ${authorities}" th:text="${authority.Name}">
        </div>
    </div> //reset iter to 0
</div>
```

After one loop in role, I would like to reset iter to 0 or whatever value.

It is possible?

Answer (score 0):

From thymeleaf [tutorial](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status):

> Status variables are defined within a th:each attribute and contain
>   the following data:
>
> - The current iteration index, starting with 0. This is the index property.
> - The current iteration index, starting with 1. This is the count property.
> - The total amount of elements in the iterated variable. This is the size property.
> - The iter variable for each iteration. This is the current property.
> - Whether the current iteration is even or odd. These are the even/odd boolean properties.
> - Whether the current iteration is the first one. This is the first boolean property.
> - Whether the current iteration is the last one. This is the last boolean property.

Status variable is object of `org.thymeleaf.engine.IterationStatusVar` type, so if you check its [source code](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/blob/3.0-master/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/engine/IterationStatusVar.java) you will see that there are no setters nor public fields.

So, you can't change any of values that `iter` provides.

Comment: right. can we declare another counter in thymeleaf?

Comment: no, you can't.  in general, thymeleaf vars are immutable.

Comment: @Sml004 you can't. Thymeleaf vars are immutable.